# If I use interventionimage caching where do cached files get saved?

Tags: laravel, intervention

Hi I am using interventionimage and wanted to try image caching which is an optional package that needs to be installed. I am wondering however where do cached images get saved, in what folder? Are they saved in the same folder where original image is from? This is not mentioned anywhere, does anyone know?

Answer (score 0):

All cache saving logic will depend on you cache driver settings.
If you are using file cacheing (default) in a typical Laravel installation then the files are stored in  following directory

```
<your app>/storage/framework/cache
```